# Python IF True/False

Tags: python, if-statement

When "Python" is detected in the text (or not) it outputs either True or False.
Now i want to take those and use them to print different statements like "is there" or "is not" but
i doesn't work.

```
Text = "Python for beginners"
print("Python" in Text)

if Text == True:
    print("Its there!")
else:
    print("its not there")
```

The problem is probably with the `if Text == True:` statement but I just cant get it right.
I already tried `if Text is True:` and `if Text == "True":`however nothing worked. So if someone here could help me out id be really happy

Comment: You already wrote the right test earlier: `"Python" in Text`

Comment: `if "Python" in Text:`

Comment: Text = "Python" in Text;
print(Text)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Try to take a step back and think about the code logically. What is the value of `Text`? It's that string that you assigned to it, right? Is that string *equal to* `True`? (Hint: no, it is not. No string is equal to `True`, and no string is equal to `False`, either.) What is the thing that you want to compare to `True`? Well, it's the result of the test you did, right? Okay, so how are you planning to *use the value* from that test? (Hint: if you wanted to test whether `3 * 4 == 12`, would it be useful to `print(3 * 4)` first? Why or why not?)

Comment: After that, consider whether it's actually useful to compare things to `True`. Hint: it generally is not. After all, would you ever say: "if it is true that it is raining, I will need an umbrella"? I rather imagine you would simply say "if it is raining, I will need an umbrella".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the right check in your print statement `"Python" in text`, you just don't use it in the right way. You can either store the value in a variable:

```py
is_found = "Python" in text

if is_found:
    print("Its there!")
else:
    print("its not there")
```

or use it directly in the conditional:

```py
if "Python" in text:
    print("Its there!")
else:
    print("its not there")
```

but by just printing the value, you are unable to access the value later in your conditional without repeating the same check.

Answer (score 1):

You are only printing the check you made earlier, you would want something like this:

```py
Text = "Python for beginners"

if "Python" in Text:
    print("Its there!")
else:
    print("its not there")
```

What happens here is python will run

```py
"Python" in Text
```

as an expression that will return `True`, and so it will go into the `if` statement, and print the `Its there!`.

Answer (score 1):

```py
Text = "Python for beginners"

if "Python" in Text:
    print("Its there!")
else:
    print("Its not there")
```

Now It will print .